# TFS Rest API - Getting a test case by test case name or title

Tags: c#, tfs

I'm writing a custom TFS REST API client.
I decided to use the C# WorkItemTrackingHttpClient and JsonPatchDocument/JsonPatchOperation . These Objects seem to suit my purpose well.
My question is how can I retrieve and update a test case by it's name or title (string) rather than by it's ID (the ID is not supposed to be known by the clients users, just the test name)
I tried to add a HTTP query to the URL , but so far have been unsuccessful.

I'm trying to use the following URL :

GET http://XXXX:8081/tfs/{Project}/_apis/test/plans?name="KuKu"

but I'm always getting multiple Test Cases instead of the one with that name.

Thanks,
Yigal.

Answer (score 1):

> TFS Rest API - Getting a test case by test case name or title

There is no such directly way or REST API can achieve this.

As workaround, you could try to use the REST API [Test Suites - Get Test Cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/test-suites/get-test-cases?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0) to get the ID of the testcase:

```
GET https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/test/Plans/{planId}/suites/{suiteId}/testcases?api-version=5.0
```

[image]

Then we could use the REST API [Work Items - Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0) with above `ID` to get the `System.Title` and just determine if the `System.Title` meets the expected value:

```
GET https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=5.0
```

[image]

So, we just need to loop the id of the testcase and check the `System.Title` for this request.